# Access token for Microsoft Graph API is immediately expired

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm following [this guide](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service) to authenticate to the Microsoft Graph API, and using Postman I can `POST` to the `/token` endpoint successfully get a token:

[image: post to get token]

Now, copying that token and pasting it into `Authorization: Bearer {{token}}`, I try to make a request to `https://graph.windows.net/my-tenant/me?api-version=1.6/`, but the response I get says

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Authentication_ExpiredToken",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request."
        },
        "date": "2018-05-23T08:05:10",
        "requestId": "f56bcd26-4314-41c6-81b6-e6540aa7b0ae",
        "values": null
    }
}
```

How can the token I just created be expired?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I doubt the token is expired, the message seems off.

You are trying to call Azure AD Graph API with a token for MS Graph API.
Change your scope to `https://graph.windows.net/.default`, or call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`.

Also, you cannot call the `/me` endpoint after using client credentials flow. There is no signed in user. You have to use `/users/object-id-or-upn`

Comment: Use microsoft graph scope token to call AAD graph api is absolutely wrong. But I also think that getting signed user with client credentails flow should not work. It needs user sign in.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried changing the endpoint before, but apparently then I had called graph.*windows*.com rather than graph.*microsoft*.com, and when that didn't work I gave that up and tried other things. Now it worked.

I also see why `/me` can't work in this context; the `/users` endpoint works now, though, so I'm all happy :)

Answer (score 0):

For others experiencing this issue in the future: this issue also happens if there is a GUID in your initial token request with CAPITAL letters in it. The endpoint will accept and issue a token, but for any resource the comparison breaks. So, use small caps in your guids :)